# How to configure dynamically includePath in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, go-to-definition

In my project, there are two sub projects: `basis_libs` and `services`.

```
./-
  |--- basis_libs
  |        |--- xxx
  |        ...
  |        |--- yyy
  |
  |--- services
          |--- server1
          |--- server2
          |--- server3
          ...
          |--- servern
```

The directory `basis_libs` can be regarded as some basis, common libs, which will be used by all of developers. The directory `services` contains all of servers, which are developed by developers.

Let's say I'm developing the `server2`. The problem is that when I try to "goto definition" on a function, in the directory `server2`, all of hints will popup, including the functions with same name in other servers, such as `server1`, `server3` etc.

It there some way to solve this issue?

Here is my `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/services/",
                "${workspaceFolder}/services/common/**",
                "${workspaceFolder}/basis_libs/",
                "${workspaceFolder}/basis_libs/xxx/",
                "${workspaceFolder}/basis_libs/yyy/aaa/",
                "${workspaceFolder}/basis_libs/yyy/bbb/ccc"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```